# XAMPP Upgrade - Error #1045 on Creating New User

Tags: xampp, mysql-error-1045

I'm trying to upgrade my **XAMPP** from **1.7.3** to **1.7.4** (*xampp-win32-1.7.4-VC6-installer.exe*). I had already backed up the **htdocs** & **mysql/data** folders. I uninstalled XAMPP & deleted the remaining content *(to avoid the incomplete uninstall problem I had earlier)*. I then installed XAMPP 1.7.4. Everything worked fine. I'm able to add new user with all privileges granted. But when I copied the backed-up folders to their respective places, I can no longer grant privileges to new users. I get this error message:

```
ERROR 1045: Access denied for user: 'root@localhost' (Using password: NO)
```

I had tried many solutions that the web can offer, including resetting the password, but nothing seems to work. In fact, after resetting the password, and other modifications I tried related to that, I get "**Cannot connect: invalid settings**" error message when accessing **phpmyadmin**, the server rejected the connection.

This happened after I copied the backed-up **mysql/data/mysql** folder. Specifically, I think it's the **user.*** files from that folder that trigger the problem. But if I didn't copy those files or revert them with the original files, my backed-up **users** cannot be accessed in that I get "**Error establishing a database connection**" when opening my site, but I can create new user and grant it privileges again.

What is in the **user.*** files that's causing the problem? And how can I fix this?

---

> **UPDATE :**
>
> Further research shows that the **1.7.4** version is actually very
>   **VERY** buggy...
>   http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=44327
>
> So the question now is: **Is it worth upgrading?**

Comment: You restored backed up files? Did those perchance include the mysql data directories? If so, you've restored your OLD database, with the old usernames/passwords in the Db.

Comment: Yes, I had read about that and tried resetting the password with no avail...

Comment: Anyway, what does the **VC6** stand for in the installer file name? Does anyone know?

Comment: `Visual C++ 6.0` - the compiler that generated the binaries for your version. There's known issues with VC6 v.s VC9 builds of certain packages, so the windows builds for PHP indicate which compiler was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm convinced that version **1.7.4** is just not stable enough and would take reverting back to **1.7.3** as the solution... (see link in my *update* section in the question)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to completely uninstall the xampp.I use both xampp and wamp to access my DBs.Install wamp then set up passwords depending on your desire and again set the same password on the xampp phpMyadmin,You will absolutely 
enjoy using both servers .Enjoy your time!

Comment: Tx for the tips. But now I'm using XAMPP 1.7.7 for any new projects I'm doing and kept version 1.7.3 if I ever wanted to access the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to shut down mysql prior to copying over the data files? Sometimes if the DB is left running it will corrupt the files as they try to overwrite.

Comment: Yes, I have done that and rechecked to make sure the process is stopped.

Comment: Was there a change in the mysql core tables? Perhaps it is looking for fields that were added in the newer version, but you overwrote them.  I am out of options if that is not the case. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, after further research, apparently, there is changes in the tables... I also found out that the version is actually very buggy. I updated my question above with the link from the forum.